# Subset of a k- ideal is k-ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity 1.  The collection of ideals of $R$ is denoted by $S$ which forms a commutative semiring.  $A(R)$ is the set of all ideals with nonzero annihilator i.e., $A(R)$ is an annihilating ideal that is an ideal $I$ of $R$ is said to be an annihilating ideal if there exists a nonzero ideal $J$ of $R$ such that $IJ = (0)$.
An ideal $I$ is said to be $K$-ideal if $x \in I, x+y \in I$, then $y\in I$.

We know that "in ring every ideal is $k$-ideal".
Therefore, I think that the ideals in semiring $S$ forms a $k$-ideal and the ideals in $A(R)$ forms $k$-ideal. Is my opinion is acceptable or not

Comment: Next time, instead of asserting your "opinion" on what you think is true, why don't you include your work? If you did have a candidate proof for the first "opinion," then it would be valuable to know where you went wrong.  Just throwing stuff on the wall and seeing what sticks is an unacceptable style of posting. You would not fare well very long doing that.

Answer (score 0):

I'll prefer to use $\mathcal I(R)$ for the semiring of ideals of $R$ and $\mathcal A(R)$ for the subset of annihilating ideals to try to keep the notation more readable.

> Therefore, I think that the ideals in semiring $S$ forms a $k$-ideal

Nope.

Let $R=\mathbb R[x]/(x^3)$ and $I_1$ be the ideal generated by $x$, $I_2$ be the ideal generated by $x^2$.

Then $A=\{0, I_1\}$ is a semiring ideal of $\mathcal I(R)$, and $I_1+I_2=I_1\in A$, but $I_2\notin A$.

> and the ideals in $A(R)$ forms $k$-ideal

Yes and the solution is trivial.

Suppose $I+J\in \mathcal A(R)$ for any ideals $I,J$. Then there exists a nonzero ideal $B$ such that $(I+J)B=\{0\}$. But then $\{0\}\subseteq JB\subseteq (I+J)B\subseteq \{0\}$. So *both* ideals are annihilator ideals. Assuming $I$ is an annihilator ideal never even comes into play. So not only does $\mathcal A(R)$ "additively absorb," it is even "additively saturated."